# How to show the print dilaog to select the option to print when clicked on "print" from the license agreement installer screen using NSIS

Tags: nsis

How to show the print dialog to select the option to print when clicked on "print" from the license agreement installer screen using NSIS.

I want to display the below screen when clicked on "Print" from the License agreement screen.

If i use the below command it is directly printing the page without popping up the Print dialog.

Comment: Which command are you using now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in support but you can display this [common dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlgbox/print-dialog-box) with the system plug-in:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!define /IfNDef PD_HIDEPRINTTOFILE 0x00100000
!define /IfNDef PD_NOSELECTION 0x00000004
!define /IFNDef PD_USEDEVMODECOPIESANDCOLLATE 0x00040000 ; Just one copy


Function ShowPrintDlg
System::Call '*(p0,p$hwndparent,p0,p0,p,i${PD_HIDEPRINTTOFILE}|${PD_NOSELECTION}|${PD_USEDEVMODECOPIESANDCOLLATE},&i2,&i2,&i2,&i2,&i2,p,p,p,p,p0,p0,p0,p0,&l.r0)p.r1'
System::Call '*$1(ir0)'
System::Call 'COMDLG32::PrintDlg(pr1)i.r0'
${If} $0 <> 0
    System::Call '*$1(p,p,p.r3,p.r4,t""r2)'
    System::Free $1
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::GlobalFree(pr3)'
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::GlobalLock(pr4)p.r1'
    ${If} $1 P<> 0
        System::Call '*$1(&i2,&i2.r2,&i2,&i2)'
        System::Call '*$1(&i$2,&t999.r2)'
        System::Call 'KERNEL32::GlobalUnlock(pr1)'
        System::Call 'KERNEL32::GlobalFree(pr4)'
    ${EndIf}
    MessageBox mb_ok 'User wants to print to "$2"'
${Else}
    System::Free $1
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Page InstFiles

Section
Call ShowPrintDlg
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Hi @Anders, Thank you for the solution. It helped me a lot.